# Limiting the queryset RelatedFields to only currently related objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am overriding the `get_queryset` function in serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField to something like this achieve what I described in the title:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.queryset
    if self.root.instance:
        return queryset.filter(**{str(self.root.instance._meta.verbose_name_plural) :
                                      self.root.instance})
    else:
        return queryset
```

This feels like an extremely hacky way to achieve it. Is there a cleaner syntax for getting related objects given a queryset and a root instance? I want the function to be generic so I can use it elsewhere. Or is there a rest framework's recommended way of setting queryset?

Comment: What if there are multiple `ForeignKey`s that refer to that model. It does not look like a good idea in the first place to do such filtering. The *Zen of Python* says *explicit* over *implicit*, this is definitely something I think is better made explicit.

Comment: I think the child class that inherit this class will have the burden of making the usage explicit. Here, I want to create an abstract layer. On a side note, I suppose using ContentType instead of using string is one way to clean it up.

Comment: please clarify your question and goal